# Metodo storage cuando hago update manda a una ruta distinta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

cuando intento hacer un update de mi perfil de usuario, especificamente en la parte del avatar, cuando se crea el usuario, no hay ningun problema, pero al hacer el update me lo guarda de esta manera `/private/var/tmp/phpkvpriG` al hacer un `dd` o `return`, me muestra correctamente la ruta `public/uxxs4f8ufQEzTOguMMzigwHOdR6HtGvIiq8AeGNb.png`, en mi controlador lo tengo de esta manera el metodo update

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        // return $request->file('avatar')->store('public');
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize($user);
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar'))
        {
            $user->avatar = $request->file('avatar')->store('public');
        }
        $user->update($request->all());
        $user->roles()->sync($request->roles);
        return back()->with('info', 'Usuario Actualizado');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que veo es que en esta línea le asignas el valor de la ruta al archivo al atributo avatar, pero no lo guardas:

```
$user->avatar = $request->file('avatar')->store('public');
```

y aunque lo guardases ahí, luego lo sobreescrbirías en esta otra línea

```
$user->update($request->all());
```

pues usas los datos del request sin tener en cuenta el nuevo dato de la ruta.

Hay varias maneras de evitarlo, una simple puede ser guardando los datos del request en una variable, y asignar el valor de la ruta del archivo al elemento del array correspondiente en esa variable, y finalmente usar los datos de la variable para actualizar la BD:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['avatar'] = $request->file('avatar')->store('public');
$user->update($data);
```

Todo el método:

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize($user);
    $data = $request->all();
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar'))
        $data['avatar'] = $request->file('avatar')->store('public');
    $user->update($data);
    $user->roles()->sync($request->roles);
    return back()->with('info', 'Usuario Actualizado');
}
```

Comment: Esta parte que me pusiste sirvio mas sin en cambio estoy haciendo dos veces el metodo update y no creo que sea necesario, en principio me sirvio pero en el metodo update en $request->all(), use el metodo except y le pase como array el campo avatar, es solo una solucion alternativa

Comment: No entendí bien lo que explicas en el comentario, pero si encontraste una solución diferente, creo que podrías [escribir una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), y aceptarla como la que responde tu pregunta. Ten en cuenta que para los que lean después, cuantas más opciones válidas, mejor. Y a esta respuesta, si te sirvió, puedes votarla. Creo que es eso mas o menos lo que se [sugiere](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [alienta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) en SO.